# The use of Settings.Settings file in a Web Applicaiton

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have inhertied an web application (.Net MVC) to support. I have noticed that the previous developer has created a class library (myApp.Core) and used a settings file (AppSettings.settings) to store application specific settings, I also can see an associated app.config file that has all the settings defined in:

```
 <applicationSettings>
    <myApp.Core.AppSettings>
        <setting name="DaysToKeep" serializeAs="String">
            <value>2</value>
        </setting>
        ...
    </myApp.Core.AppSettings>
 </applicationSettings>
```

I undersatnd that using a settings file gives nice strongly typed values and they can be stored agasint a user or application and the values can be accessed in code using the following notation:

```
AppSettings.Default.DaysToKeep;
```

However recently a change was required to update one of these setting's values on a production server (to issue a quick fix) however I was unable to locate where the actual app.settings file was located on the server and the exact setting and value to change.

Locally I can see myApp.core.dll.config in myApp.Core bin folder.

So... Where is the app.config file located on the web server? Also reading numberous articles seems to suggest that these values can't be upadted anyway, is this true.

Comment: If this is an application, not a website, it will be an app.config.  If this is a website it will be a web.config.  However, in most cases you do not HAVE to have the .config file since the compiler rolls the values up in the .dll.  So, it is entirely possible that you are either looking for the wrong file or the original developer never deployed the .config to the production environment.

Comment: This solution is a combination of Web wapplication and class libaries, the main application being the web(mvc) application with supporting projects(class libraries) such as Core,DAL etc.... I do think that the values are rolled up into the dll.

Comment: Right, so it's going to have a web.config instead of an app.config.  The application will traverse its subfolders until it reaches the application root, as defined by IIS. If you don't see a web.config anywhere in that folder structure then one wasn't published. You should be able to just drop the one from the dev environment out there in the IIS root and it should grab it first, then it falls back to what's compiled in the DLL.